# How to run remote linux command that won't stop after closing shell

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, ssh, terminal

There is a Linux terminal command that I want to run on a remote machine.  I can ssh to the machine and begin executing the command (it's output being directed to an output file); however, once I close the ssh connection and close my terminal window, the command stops.  How can I have the command continue to execute even once I exit the remote machine?

Comment: This isn't usually how how linux works ... A command would keep running on the 'server' even after disconnecting from ssh ... Could you describe what linux distribution you have, and what command you are trying to run?

Comment: It's a RedHat machine and the command is executing a java program.  The command itself wouldn't make much sense to you because its proprietary.

Comment: Have you tried adding the ampersand after the command? Example: `runThis -params &`

Comment: I've had a little thought, and was wondering if the command you are trying to run is a 'terminal' command. So, for example, if I ssh into a server, and use `vi filename`, that's not going to run on the server. I've never had to get around this problem, but with a little google, it seems that `nohup` may be able to help

Comment: Start up a screen session on the remote machine and run your java command inside it.  Then, you can detach the `screen` (or `tmux`) session (ctrl-b d) and it will continue running even after you disconnect.  Even better, the next time you connect to the machine, you can reattach the `screen` session and see what the command did or how it exited, just as if you never left.

Comment: Have you tried to nohup and double-background it? Also, "detach" the stdout and stderr descriptors. Run it like this: ( ( nohup mycommand 1>/dev/null 2>&1 ) & )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using [screen](http://linux.die.net/man/1/screen). From the man page:

> Programs continue to run when their window is currently not visible
>   and even when the whole screen session is detached from the user's
>   terminal

An alternative is [nohup](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup).